# Right way to phrase MySQL query across many (possible empty) tables

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to do what I think is a set of simple set operations on a database table: several intersections and one union.  But I don't seem to be able to express that in a simple way.

I have a MySQL table called Moment, which has many millions of rows.  (It happens to be a time-series table but that doesn't impact on my problem here; however, these data have a column 'source' and a column 'time', both indexed.)  Queries to pull data out of this table are created dynamically (coming in from an API), and ultimately boil down to a small pile of temporary tables indicating which 'source's we care about, and maybe the 'time' ranges we care about.

Let's say we're looking for

```
(source in Temp1) AND (
    ((source in Temp2) AND (time > '2017-01-01')) OR
    ((source in Temp3) AND (time > '2016-11-15'))
)
```

Just for excitement, let's say Temp2 is empty --- that part of the API request was valid but happened to include 'no actual sources'.

If I then do

```
SELECT m.* from Moment as m,Temp1,Temp2,Temp3
WHERE (m.source = Temp1.source) AND (
  ((m.source = Temp2.source) AND (m.time > '2017-01-01')) OR
  ((m.source = Temp3.source) AND (m.time > '2016-11'15'))
)
```

... I get a heaping mound of nothing, because the empty Temp2 gives an empty Cartesian product before we get to the WHERE clause.

Okay, I can do

```
SELECT m.* from Moment as m
  LEFT JOIN Temp1 on m.source=Temp1.source
  LEFT JOIN Temp2 on m.source=Temp2.source
  LEFT JOIN Temp3 on m.source=Temp3.source
WHERE (m.source = Temp1.source) AND (
  ((m.source = Temp2.source) AND (m.time > '2017-01-01')) OR
  ((m.source = Temp3.source) AND (m.time > '2016-11-15'))
)
```

... but this takes >70ms even on my relatively small development database.

If I manually eliminate the empty table,

```
SELECT m.* from Moment as m,Temp1,Temp3
WHERE (m.source = Temp1.source) AND (
  ((m.source = Temp3.source) AND (m.time > '2016-11-15'))
)
```

... it finishes in 10ms.  That's the kind of time I'd expect.

I've also tried putting a single unmatchable row in the empty table and doing SELECT DISTINCT, and it splits the difference at ~40ms.  Seems an odd solution though.

This really feels like I'm just conceptualizing the query wrong, that I'm asking the database to do more work than it needs to.  What is the Right Way to ask the database this question?

Thanks!

**--UPDATE--**

I did some actual benchmarks on my actual database, and came up with some really unexpected results.

For the scenario above, all tables indexed on the columns being compared, with an empty table,

- doing it with left joins took 3.5 minutes (!!!)
- doing it without joins (just 'FROM...WHERE') and adding a null row to the empty table, took 3.5 seconds

even more striking, when there *wasn't* an empty table, but rather ~1000 rows in each of the temporary tables,

- doing the whole thing in one query took 28 minutes (!!!!!), but,
- doing each of the three AND clauses separately and then doing the final combination in the code took less than a second.

I still feel I'm expressing the query in some foolish way, since again, all I'm trying to do is one set union (OR) and a few set intersections.  It really seems like the DB is making this gigantic Cartesian product when it seriously doesn't need to.  All in all, as pointed out in the answer below, keeping some of the intelligence up in the code seems to be the better approach here.

Comment: The key is the assiduous use of indexes - and then hardware

Comment: Gotcha, & thanks ... so would you say the "LEFT JOIN" query is the conceptually-correct, right-thinking one, and deal with the time separately?  I.e. that 'taking a long time' isn't the cue I'm taking it for, that I'm composing the query wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various ways to tackle the problem. Needless to say it depends on

1. how many queries are sent to the database,
2. the amount of data you are processing in a time interval,
3. how the database backend is configured to manage it.

For your use case, a little more information would be helpful. The optimization of your query by using CASE/COUNT(*) or CASE/LIMIT combinations in queries to sort out empty tables would be one option. However, if-like queries cost more time.

You could split the SQL code to downgrade the scaling of the problem from 1*N^x to y*N^z, where z should be smaller than x.

You said that an API is involved, maybe you are able handle the temporary "no data" tables differently or even don't store them?

Another option would be to enable query caching:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/query-cache-configuration.html

Comment: Thanks Michael, these are good avenues to pursue.  Primarily I'm learning (from your answer and the comment above) that there isn't a magical "better way" to do these kinds of set operations, and that keeping the intelligence up in the API code can be a better approach than trusting the database to come up with a strategy for a general-purpose request.